# Find the earliest intersection point of two moving objects

Tags: trigonometry

I'm not sure if this is a calculus question or a trig question, but here goes. I intend to use the answer to figure out how to program pathing.

*Given:*
The starting $(x,y)$ coordinates of three objects are known. Object $A$ is stationary. Object $B$ travels at a speed of $2$ units per second toward Object $A$, and may even pass it. Object $C$ moves at a speed of $5$ units per second in an effort to intercept Object $B$ at the soonest possible time.

*Find:*
Find the coordinates of the intersection between Object $B$ and Object $C$.

Here is a possible illustration:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parametric equation of object $B$ is ${\bf b} = {\bf a} + t {\bf v}$, where $\bf a$ and $\bf v$ are constant vectors.  If object $C$ moves with speed $s$ and starts from point $\bf c$ at time $0$, at time $t$ it can be anywhere at distance $st$ from $\bf c$.
So you want to solve
$$ ({\bf a} - {\bf c} + t {\bf v} ) \cdot ({\bf a} - {\bf c} + t {\bf v} ) = s^2 t^2$$
which is a quadratic equation in $t$, and take the least positive solution (if there is one).